# Google Sheets Importxml not import plain text

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I can't import unstructured text, will there be any other way? any help is appreciated

URL: https://rucsoundings.noaa.gov/get_soundings.cgi?data_source=GFS&start=latest&airport=SACO

[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `IMPORTDATA`:

```
=IMPORTDATA("https://rucsoundings.noaa.gov/get_soundings.cgi?data_source=GFS&start=latest&airport=SACO")
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

it was solved with script like: https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/beginner-apis/